# How can I track when a WPF MediaElement is loading?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I have some simple code/xaml to show a video. Eventually I'll bind some model object to this control that contains the path to the video and some other info so I can add other functionality to this control. The problem I'm having is: it takes about a second for the video to start playing when I click the play button.

It's not a big deal, but I will be modifying this control's visibility based on if video is playing, and I'd prefer not to show this control until the video is actually playing. So, **how can I programatically detect when the video has finished loading/buffering/whatever, and therefore know that I am able to show smooth playback?**

I tried binding Labels to the MediaElement's IsBuffering and IsLoaded properties to see if they would change at all, but they always show false. I also bound to Source and IsMouseOver to make sure there was no issue with my bindings. Source shows the correct path and IsMouseOver updates as expected when I move the mouse over the playing video. Given that, I don't think there's any issue with the bindings.

I also added event listeners in the code behind to buffering started/ended, and the methods never get run.

A workaround would be to add a second of blackscreen to the start of the video, and then keep the control hidden until MediaElement.Position got to 1 second, but that feels a bit too hacky. I also don't know of any way to add blackscreen to the start of a video outside of using video editing software and re-rendering the entire video, which is extremely tedious.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestProject.Controls.MediaElementControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MediaElement, Path=IsBuffering}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MediaElement, Path=IsLoaded}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MediaElement, Path=Source}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MediaElement, Path=IsMouseOver}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <MediaElement Grid.Row="1" Name="MediaElement"
                  LoadedBehavior="Manual"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  Source="C:\Temp\SomeVideo.mp4" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" x:Name="PlayButton" Content="Play" Click="PlayButton_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MediaElementControl : UserControl
{
    private Stopwatch _debugStopwatch;

    public MediaElementControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _debugStopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        // Breakpoints in these methods never hit
        MediaElement.BufferingStarted += MediaElement_BufferingStarted;
        MediaElement.BufferingEnded += MediaElement_BufferingEnded;
    }

    private void MediaElement_BufferingStarted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _debugStopwatch.Start();
    }

    private void MediaElement_BufferingEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _debugStopwatch.Stop();
    }

    private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement.Play();
    }
}
```